# Loop with sync download not updating label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

so I'm trying to download a bunch of files (pretty small ones) with synchronous downloads - sync because the files are pretty small and I do not want the user to do anything with the interface while the download batch is running.

Somehow though the updates to the interface, which are located within the loop, do not get executed. I know, that a sync download blocks the whole thread but shouldn't it still execute all those interface updates in between the downloads?

```
            bool error = false;
            int counter = 1;
            while (!error)
            {
                //The label I want to update with status updates
                lblProgress.Content = "Downloading page " + counter.ToString() + ":";

                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(URL), targetPath);
                        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(targetPath);
                    }
                    //I'm using the catch statement because I download a bunch of files 
                    //without knowing how many there are - so when I get the 404 I 
                    //know, it's done.
                    catch { error = true; }
                }
                counter++;
            }
```

Thank you for any responds!

Edit:
I just realized, that all the other interface changes in the whole method do not get executed before the downloads are done.
The method should set the label to another text several lines before that loop and even this is not showing up...

Comment: There was a notorious API called Application.DoEvents() that is for this purpose, it is like saying “Hey, let’s take a little break from this long running loop, let’s repaint the UI so user knows we are not dead. Come back to this loop after the UI has been repaint.”. The idea is you call it in the loop, after setting the Text of the label.

Comment: But this is a lousy workaround, not sure if it works for WPF either. For your requirement there is nothing wrong to use async download, keeping the UI responsive while downloading. All you need to do is disable the controls temporarily so user cannot click them.

Comment: @kennyzx the problem I have with that is, that the files downloaded are so small, that the invokes of opening a new thread etc to run an async are actually noticable slower than the sync dl. I know it is bad form but I tried it and sync actually seems to suit better here... But I will definitely check out this method. The thing with async is, in that moment when it's invoked it actually blocks the main thread as well and b/c of the filesize the effect is ultimately the same... I guess "don't dl hundreds of micro files"...

Comment: Nope. The async methods don't block at all. If something is blocking, it's not this. Also, the `WebClient` class can be event driven, not just async. Explore it.

Comment: Assuming you have the UI update in a Dispatcher Invoke, you might have the UI thread all blocked up. This would prevent the UI from updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer your question I have created an example (does not use MVVM). The following code uses async method to make sure UI thread is not being blocked by the code to download file from the internet.

Now, to answer your question about interface changes being rendered after downloads are done, event handler which download the file is executed on UI thread and when you change any property on other controls from the handler (for example, setting text of the label/texblock) the control will understand the change and will render it self when UI thread is available, but as you are still downloading files on the UI thread any change to the UI controls from within even handler will be rendered when UI thread becomes idle again which will happen after event handler finishes execution. I hope now you have a good idea about why UI is not updated immediately when you change text of the label from the event handler.

Code with async method:

**Mainwindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="600">
    <Window.Resources>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtUrl" />
        <Button Content="Start" x:Name="btnStart" Click="Button_Click" />
        <Label x:Name="lblProgress" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Mainwindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool error = false;
            string url = txtUrl.Text;
            int counter = 1;

            btnStart.IsEnabled = false;
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (!error)
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { lblProgress.Content = "Downloading page " + counter.ToString() + ":"; });

                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string targetPath = $"c:\\temp\\downloads\\file{counter}.tmp";
                            wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), targetPath);
                        }
                        catch { error = true; }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            });
            btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

An alternative method could just await the `DownloadFileTaskAsync` method, and thus avoid the need for `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool error = false;
    string url = txtUrl.Text;
    int counter = 1;

    btnStart.IsEnabled = false;

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        while (!error)
        {
            lblProgress.Content = "Downloading page " + counter.ToString() + ":";
            string targetPath = $"c:\\temp\\downloads\\file{counter}.tmp";

            try
            {
                await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, targetPath);
            }
            catch
            {
                error = true;
            }

            counter++;
        }
    }

    btnStart.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I would replace `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `Task.Run`.

Comment: Holy ♥♥♥ this is awsome... I've settled for the second variant, I definately underestimated async stuff... This works exactly like I need it! Thank you loads for opening my eyes! Cheers

Comment: And yes I do understand now while the UI is not beeing updated. I thought it would update when I command it to, not when the thread becomes idle... Thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 1):

> I know, that a sync download blocks the whole thread but shouldn't it still execute all those interface updates in between the downloads?

How is it supposed to update the UI while it downloades the files or executes a while loop? A single thread cannot do two things simultaneously.

You should either download the file on a background thread if you want to be able to update the UI during the meantime, or better yet use the asynchronous `DownloadFileAsync` method, e.g.:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        lblProgress.Content = "Downloading page " + counter.ToString();
        await wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(URL), targetPath);
        FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(targetPath);
        counter++;
    }
    catch
    {
        //...
        return;
    }
}
```

In your sample code, it's a bit unclear why you are using a loop since you seem to download the same file all over again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For clarification: there is quite a bunch of logic in the loop to determine the URL but thats a lot of code and not related to this particular problem so I decided to crop it from my code in the question.